# Google Fit Health data access

Tags: android

Requirement is like clinician & patient related. Clinician can access all patient(i.e 100 patient) data from google fit.

Any idea ? can we do with google fit ? if yes then please elaborate.

We have already implemented google fit for review own data.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Be sure to mention what you're trying to achieve and you've already tried. How did it work out? Where did you get stuck? Be sure to include some code snippets and logs.

Comment: If user login with own account that will work and it working fine.  i want doctor can access his patient Google fit account  data. is there any option to give right to another user for only google fit data. ?